# Program icon not showing up after Clean and Build (Netbeans)

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I'm new at Java and also swing. I just created a small app using JFrame and added some buttons and textFields, also I have a method which set the icon that I want for the taskbar and the one in the left corner.

When I run the program in Netbeans everything seems correctly, but when I build the project the icon it's not showing up. I tried a lot of things but none of them worked for me.

here's the method that I use for the program:

```
    private void setIcon() {
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/main/java/icons/steam.png");
        this.setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());
    }
```

And I call the method from the constructor.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

Implementing what Andrew said, now I have this:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            URL url = getClass().getResource("src/main/java/icons/steam.png");
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        this.setIconImage(img);
```

And that's on the constructor. But when I run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
```

I tried different paths but I can't get it. And yes, I'm sure that "steam.png" is there.

Comment: `new ImageIcon("src/main/java/icons/steam.png");` Huh.. it's that time of day again. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. **BTW:** Handy tip for loading images. Use. ImageIO! Creating an image icon can fail silently, but `ImageIO.read(..)` produces a helpful stack trace when something goes wrong.

Comment: Check the image is actually in the Jar in the location you presume. Are you using Windows? A handy tip. A Jar file is just a specialized Zip file. Rename (a copy of) the Jar to end in `.zip` then double click to open & explore. Another thing: I would always use the `/` prefix that alerts the class loader to look for the class from the root of the Jar.

Comment: I opened the .jar with WinRAR, and I can't see any folder named "icons", and I don't know why. I have the "icons" folder under "src/main/java/icons" and also tried "src/icons".
 I edited the source path too, adding / as a prefix, so I have:

"/icons/steam.png"

Comment: OK .. some IDEs require resources to be in a specific path before they'll put them in the final Jar. For some it is the `resources` directory / package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I been looking for a solution to this and I finally get it (thanks to Andrew trough the comments)

First I edited my code as you can see in **EDIT 1**

After that, I got an `IllegalArgumentException` and the problem was that I didn't have a "resources" folder under `/src`

So I created my resources folder under `src/main/resources` and put my image inside

Then I got it using

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/icons/steam.png");
img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

And that was the fix for my problem, now when I run the program images are now loaded.

Thank you so much!